# The marriage problem on NBC's "The Voice"

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I'm a long time lurker here just never got around to registering so excuse the lack of reputation points.

So most people here are aware of the marriage problem:  You're given a known number of potential mates who you may interview and either deny and never see them again or accept and marry and you're done and can't interview any others. The answer as I remember is that you interview the first 1/e of the candidates and then pick the next best one you see.

I don't know how many of you are rotting your brain with NBC's "The Voice". But the rules are similar but enough different that I was wondering if anyone had a good solution to this.

First, there are a known number of singers auditioning to be coached by a famous artist. There are four artists listening to the singers and can choose or deny them. If one artist chooses a singer, the singer is assigned to the artist. If more than one artist choose a singer the singer chooses which artist to work with. And finally, each artist only had 8 spots open for singers.

So in addition to having 8 spots rather than 1 like the marriage problem. You also have some game theory with the artists competing for singers.

Any good ideas for an optimal strategy for picking your 8 ten members?

Comment: Sorry for the typos. Did this on my iPhone and it's hard to go back and edit the post. 

Comment: If you're going to worry about the way the artists are going to compete for talent, you need to figure out what kind of hypotheses you mean to add on what the artists know. If they don't know anything about each other's choices, their strategy is not going to be affected. Or do you assume that they all rank the singers in exactly the same way?

Comment: I would assume that since it's a repeated game for each singer. The artists will learn how everyone else ranks a singer. But that's a good point. Maybe some human performance modeling is the way to go. 

Comment: Step 1: get Javier Colon on your team.  The other steps involve more mathematics, but I'm not convinced they will affect the outcome so much.

Comment: @OP:  What have you worked out for yourself?  In any case, I'm pretty sure you're Cee Lo Green, so I don't want to answer this question for fear of giving you an unfair advantage over Christina Aguilera.

Comment: The "marriage problem" you're referring to is also called the secretary problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).  You interview the first $n/e$ candidates (not $1/e$), where $n$ is the number of candidates and $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

Comment: To somewhat amplify J.R.N.'s remark; in fact when I hear 'marriage problem' I think of Graph Theory (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem ) 

Perhaps except if the context is obviously non-mathematical; but only perhaps ;) 

Comment: @miked, I now notice that you said "the first 1/e of the candidates."  This is correct.  (I thought you had written "the first 1/e candidates," hence my comment above.)